# Как удалить много данных условием WHERE на поле с индексом на большой и нагруженной таблице?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, sql-server, oracle

Задача чисто теоретическая, поэтому тонкости можно не уточнять. А если от тонкостей что-то зависит, то можно об этом написать.

Есть таблица c множеством записей (допустим 1M-100M), где есть поле DateTime и индекс на этом поле.
Нужно удалить тоже много записей (допустим 10k-500k), которые раньше определенного времени по полю DateTime.
Но таблица очень активно используеться в проде.
Как сделать удаление с минимальными последствиями для производительности на проде?

Какие у меня мысли возникают:

- индекс лучше не использовать, так как при удалении большого количества записей вероятно будет полный проход по таблице, где индекс не будет использован, так как это будет быстрее. Хотя не знаю этот подход можно настроить или авто постоитель плана сам все придумает по желанию.
- индекс лучше отключить на время удаления, для того что бы небыло лишних операций перестройки индекса, а после включить. Но не уверен будут ли тут проблемы с нагрузкой на проде?

Есть подходы лучше?

Еще думаю возможно есть тонкости в условии или решении:

- важно что поле типа DateTime?
- если таблица будет не большой, то это что-то меняет?
- может нагрузка на проде быть разной по своей природе, так что на производительность вообще не повлияет удаление или всегда точно повлияет?

Comment: Индекс лучше не трогать и делать удаление небольшими порциями. Некоторые БД при блокировании большого количества блоков могут перейти к полной блокировке таблицы удалением. Кроме того удаление в любом случае очень большой ввод-вывод. Собственно ему только диск и нужен. И конечно прод это почувствует, что ему диска не хватает. Так что задача сделать удаляемые порции такими, что бы прод не успевал почуствовать. И возможно между удалениями порции делать еще небольшие задержки

Comment: @Mike, как сделать реализацию такого подхода на своем языке программирования я знаю. А в рамках разных SQL синтаксисов как это можно/желательно реализовать? Вот нагуглил такое WAITFOR DELAY в ms sql server, и знаю что есть курсоры.  Или есть еще другие инструменты?

Comment: это не задача sql делать задержки. хотя в различных СУБД средства бывают. В Mysql функция sleep(), в postgresql pg_sleep. В других надо смотреть

Comment: И не вижу смысла целиком реализовывать это хранимой процедурой

Comment: тем более что удаление такого объема больше похоже на разовую задачу. Если она периодическая, то можно было бы удалять более плавно, день в день скажем. Или если у нас миллионы записей ежедневно, то возможно стоит задуматься о партиционировании и удалении партиций целиком, если СУБД поддерживает. А если не поддерживает то задуматься, а та ли выбрана БД для такой задачи

Comment: [Take Care When Scripting Batches](https://michaeljswart.com/2014/09/take-care-when-scripting-batches/)

Comment: БД предназначена для хранения данных, а не для их удаления. Продумайте дизайн так, чтобы как можно меньше надо было бы удалять.